# updates to transmission-remote torrent overwrites settings.json : how to prevevent

Tags: transmission

When I update the transmission-remote files, the update overwrites my settings.json with defaults that break my scripts.   `6.7.6-arch1-1`

How can I prevent that?

Alternatively: is there a transmission application that provides the same remote administration?